# How to add image for button in android?

Tags: android, image, button, imagebutton

How can I add an image to a button, rather than text?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Rather humorously, considering your tags, just use the [`ImageButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) widget.

Answer (score 28):

Simply use ImageButton View and set image for it:`

```
 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
```

Answer (score 16):

As he stated, used the `ImageButton` widget. Copy your image file within the `Res/drawable/` directory of your project. While in XML simply go into the graphic representation (for simplicity) of your XML file and click on your `ImageButton` widget that you added, go to its properties sheet and click on the [...] in the `src:` field. Simply navigate to your image file. Also, make sure you're using a proper format; I tend to stick with .png files for my own reasons, but they work.

Comment: Actually helpful response, thanks! I had no idea where to put images or how to specify their location.

Answer (score 8):

You should try something like this

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/qrcode"/>
```

the `android:background="@drawable/qrcode"` will do it

Comment: [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) always picks the correct size when `wrap_content` ist used. `Button` can warp the image, especially when they are small.

Answer (score 7):

The new `MaterialButton` from the Material Components can include an icon:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/material_icon_button"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/icon_button_label_enabled"
    app:icon="@drawable/icon_24px"/>
```

You can also customize some icon properties like `iconSize` and `iconGravity`.

Reference [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/MaterialButton.md#icon-button).

Answer (score 6):

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News Feed"
        android:icon="@drawable/newsfeed" />
```

newsfeed is image in the drawable folder

Comment: This does not work.


To make a button appear with text and an icon, use the Button class with the android:drawableLeft attribute: 
`<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/button_text"

    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon">`

Comment: sorry for my late replay but it works with me 
you don't assign text for the button so it does't appear
and the question is to display button with image rather that text :)

Answer (score 3):

Put your Image in drawable folder. Here my image file name is left.png

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="118dp"
    android:layout_y="95dp"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    android:onClick="toast"
    android:text=" " />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use android:drawableright or android:drawabletop,... attributes for buttons in xml file.

For example: in xml file add this attribute for a button:

Android:drawableleft="@drawable/ic_person"

or

Android:drawableright="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

Answer (score 2):

You can create an ImageButton in your android activity_main.xml and which image you want to place in your button just paste that image in your drawable folder below is the sample code for your reference.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:onClick="prev"
    android:src="@drawable/prev"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ImageView as Button. Create an ImageView and set clickable true after in write imageView.setOnClickListener for ImageView.

```
  <ImageView
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"`
android:id="@+id/imageview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

and in Activity's oncreate:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(...
```