# Image doesn't resized even if size is defined in XML (Android Studio)

Tags: android, xml, image, button

I want to make button with image like this:
[image: What I want to make]
This button has image above its text and image is resized from 512x512.

When I searched google, there were some methods to achive this. But I thought putting `Text` and `Image` inside `LinearLayout` and register `onClick` doesn't look nice so I decided to use `drawableTop` instead.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_gps"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/main_icon_gps"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/main_btn_gps"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_h60"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/guideline_v50"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_h40" />
```

Original image is 512x512 so I made another XML file(`main_icon_gps`) inside drawable directory.

```
<!-- @drawable/main_icon_gps -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_gps"
        android:width="64dp"
        android:height="64dp"
        />
</layer-list >
```

It looked nice when inspecting in Android Studio preview but when I launched the app in AVD, image resize doesn't work properly.

[image: When looking inside Android Studio] [image: When looking inside AVD]

**To sum up**, I tried to set image size with `android:width` and `android:height` inside separate XML drawable file and it worked nicely in Android Studio preview. But Android doesn't respect width and height that I defined in XML drawable file. How to make Android respect the width and height that I've defined at XML?

I have to use same image as different size so resizing actual image or have multiple image don't seem to be best idea.
Nesting things inside `LinearLayout` isn't good idea to me but if I have to achive what I want to make, then I will use that method. Before that, I want to fix the problem that image doesn't get resized.

Comment: `android:drawableTop="@drawable/drawable_gps"` ??

Comment: how about using an `ImageButton` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20636735/8872691)

Comment: @m'hdsemps I have to insert text into button, so I can't use `ImageButton`.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya It is just WebP image file. What that image look like is shown in those images in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MaterialButton` and [`iconSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#seticonsize) attribute.

or use `VectorDrawable` instead of `png` image, in this way you can set `width` and `height` in your xml file, like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#fff"
    android:pathData="M10,20v-6h4v6h5v-8h3L12,3 2,12h3v8z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: I used WebP which is converted from a PNG file. Also as far as i know, there isn't perfect way to convert PNG to SVG file... I will look into `MaterialButton` then. Thanks!

Comment: @tetratheta I hope that with MaterialButton you will able to fix the issue